# Best way to design a model for the store for a array?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I need to import the following into a store but I am confused about the correct model or models I need to create.

here is an example of the JSON that is returned from my server. Basically its an array with 2 items, with an array in each. The field names are different in each.

I suspect I need to have more than one model and have a relationship but I am unsure where to start. Any ideas? Thanks

```
[
    firstItems: [
    {
        name : "ProductA",
        key: "XYXZ",
        closed: true
    },
    {
        name : "ProductB",
        key: "AAA",
        closed: false
    }
    ],
 secondItems : [
 {
        desc : "test2",
        misc: "3333",
    },
    {
        desc : "test1",
        misc: "123"
    }

  ]
]
```

Comment: There is nothing I see in that response that shows any relationship between first and second.  If you need this data in stores and this is the only way you can get your response then I would create 2 store for first and second.  Then do an Ajax request for the data and in the success method use the stores loadData or loadRawData methods for first and second.

Comment: What you showed is not JSON. Arrays don't have properties. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32908928/227299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not JSON, your opening and ending `[]` can become JSON by changing them to `{}` and then using the following models

Then you can model it as

```
// Abbreviated definitions of Models, it has changed starting at Ext 5
Ext.define('FirstItem', fields: ['name', 'key', 'closed'])
Ext.define('SecondItem', fields: ['desc', 'misc'])
Ext.define('TopLevel', {
    hasMany: [
       {model: 'FirstItem', name: 'firstItems'},
       {model: 'SecondItem', name: 'secondItems'}
    ]      
})
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, there is no common key between the two models how could they possibly relate?

Comment: @bakamike The OP is showing inline data, it will be one single call. If you were going to load child store dynamically, then you'd need to specify how they relate and separate AJAX requests would be made.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Yes I realize there isn't a relationship. Its the data that is returned to me. I just need to populate it in one like the example give. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [reader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) for store's proxy, it will create appropriate model on load.
If you need to load already loaded json into the store use [loadRawData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRawData) but reader you will need in any case.

Comment: So it would create a dynamic model ? on load ?  If this is the case, why do we ever need to create models in first instance ?  Just out of interest...

Comment: If you specify a model in store, proxy will create an instance of provided Model and default Ext.data.Model otherwise. "If this is the case, why do we ever need to create models in first instance ?" - didn't get the question, what you mean by "in first instance"?